# Is this a mutually exclusive event?

Tags: statistics

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
         \hline
         & X = a & X = b & \text{Total}  \\
         \hline
         Y = c & 20 & 70 & 90 \\
         \hline
         Y = d & 15 & 45 & 60 \\
         \hline
         \text{Total} & 35 & 115 & 150 \\
         \hline
\end{array}$

$P(X = a\hspace{.5 em} OR\hspace{.5 em} Y \ne c)$

Since X can be and Y can be not c at the same time, I'm guessing they are not mutually exclusive so I cannot use the following formula.

$P(X = a\hspace{.5 em} OR\hspace{.5 em} Y \ne c) = P(X = a) + P(Y \ne c) = \frac{95}{150}$

I just need to verify this is wrong or right.

Comment: You are right about that way being invalid because of the overlap. But using DeMorgan's rule your event becomes $X \neq a$ AND $Y=c$ which is only one box, and can get that easily.

Comment: $\frac{95}{150}$ is wrong and you are correct that  you cannot use that expression.  $P(X = a\text{ OR } Y \ne c) = P(X = a \text{ AND } Y \ne c)  + P(X = a \text{ AND } Y = c)  + P(X \not= a \text{ AND } Y \ne c) $ would involve mutually exclusive events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition law of probability states that $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

So the general formula should be
$$P(X=a \cup Y\not=c) = P(X=a)+P(Y\not=c) - P(X=a \cap Y\not=c)$$

The two events are mutually exclusive if they cannot happen together. This means the probabilty of both events happening is 0: $$P(X=a \cap Y\not=c)=0$$ which falls back to the formula you correctly stated for the addition probability of mutual exclusive events:
$$P(X=a \cup Y\not=c) = P(X=a)+P(Y\not=c)$$
Each of the probability terms can be readily computed from the numbers in the appropriate cells of the contingency table.